# Nginx reverse proxy for port 3001

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy, reverse

I have an express server running on port 3001 which serves a React app.

Lets say that my domain name is example.com;
What I am trying to achieve is:

1. The possibility to call https://example.net/api/getUsers
2. Redirecting from http://1.2.3.4:3001/ with port to https://example.net/
3. Basically redirecting all HTTP calls (whether as IP or domain) to https://example.net/

Could anyone help with setting up that Nginx config?
This is what I currently have under /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
server {
        server_name 1.2.3.4:3001;
        return 301 https://example.net;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;
        server_name example.net www.example.net;

        return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.net www.example.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your app is returning redirect with Location: http://1.2.3.4:3001/ 
You can rewrite it with proxy_redirect and reduce redundant stuff.

```html
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}

server {  
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  server_name example.net www.example.net;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect http://1.2.3.4:3001/ $scheme://$host/;
  }
}
```

Yes, you can add the following redirect:

```
server {
        listen 1.2.3.4:3001;
        return 301 https://example.net;
}
```

But note your react app. locally listens on localhost:3001

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
```

so ensure react app. is not listening on 1.2.3.4:3001 socket too.
Otherwise, you will get `Address already in use` error and nginx will fail to start.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It basically works, but I was wondering if there is a way to also redirect from http://1.2.3.4:3001/ to https://drsteam.net/.

Comment: I mean, my React is basically just served by my Node.js server, which listens to port 3001 and changing it is not my goal. My goal is simply to redirect IP:PORT to domain. Is it possible?

Comment: well, this sounds quite ambiguous. So for client to be able to connect to 1.2.3.4:3001, nginx should be lisitening on 1.2.3.4:3001 and perform redirect with "return" to https://example.net withing that server block.
Nevertheless, there is still redirect example in my answer for 1.2.3.4:3001.